# Difference between "Object reference not set" and "referenced memory at 0x00000000"

Tags: c#, memory, runtime-error

I've been told that in this error...

`The instruction at 0x01234567 referenced memory at 0x00000000. The memory could not be read.`

... the `0x00000000` refers to NULL.

So what is the difference between the above error and...

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

?

I'm trying to get a greater understanding of the former error above...

Comment: There is no difference, the underlying hardware exception is the same.  First exception message is the one you get in native code.  In managed code the CLR just knows that the address is special and a very common programming bug so it turns the AccessViolationException into a NullReferenceException.  Any address < 0x00010000 gets this treatment.

Answer (score 1):

The first, `The instruction at 0x01234567 referenced memory at 0x00000000. The memory could not be read.` is exception captured by operating system (Windows). Your application tries to read bytes from pointer set to 0, which is protected (unmanaged call, internal function).

Second, `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` is captured by .NET itself.

Answer (score 0):

**In Simple words,**

"The instruction at 0x01234567 referenced memory at 0x00000000. The memory could not be read." occurs when memory is located to an object, but it is empty when it shouldn't be.

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object" occurs when there are no objects created at all, and you are trying to access data of an "unborn" object.